# Get controller in use in main controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
    .when('/',{
        controller : 'mainCtrl'
    })

    .when('/worker/:id',{
        controller : 'workerCtrl'
    })

    .when('/boss/:id/',{
        controller : 'bossCtrl'
    })

app.controller('mainCtrl', function(){
    // $scope.selected = 
})
```

How to know which controller is in use in my mainCtrl? so that I can set `$scope.selected = 'boss'`or`$scope.selected = 'worker'.`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. Can you please elaborate more? why do you want to know the current controller ?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply get that from route using `$route` dependency

```
var controller = $route.current.controller
```

Comment: when I nagivate to other template, i'm using other controller, should I create a service to get it back to mainCtrl?